# How to have roman numerals at the beginning of the document?

Tags: page-numbering, roman-numerals, front-matter

The first few pages of my document (introductory material)  should be numbered using roman numerals. Starting with a specific chapter, the remaining pages should be numbered arabic, starting from one (`1`) again.

*How can i achieve this? Are there any pitfalls i need to look after?*

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you are using the `book` class, start your document with `\frontmatter`. This changes the numbering to roman numerals. Then mark the main part of with `\mainmatter`. There are also `\appendix` (which changes the chapter numbering to uppercase letters) and `\backmatter`.

Comment: This will also work with `scrbook`.

Comment: And `memoir`, too.

Answer (score 40):

If you are using an article you can use:

```
\pagenumbering{Roman} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: This works for `report` too. Also "Roman" gives you page number in capitalized characters like I, II, III, IV,... If you want that in lower case (like i, ii, iii, iv, ...) use "roman".

Answer (score 15):

`\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` will suffice for different styles of page numbering, but not for roman numbering of introductory tables (which are quite uncommon). Assuming you have only one frontmatter chapter that includes tables, the following should do the trick:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}

\chapter{foo}

Some text.

\begin{table}
\caption{bla}
\end{table}

\endgroup

\mainmatter

\chapter{bar}

Some text.

\begin{table}
\caption{blubb}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

For `report` and similar classes, replace `\frontmatter` with `\pagenumbering{Roman}` and `\mainmatter` with `\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

Comment: While using groups like this is *probably* fine, I'd be a little wary of doing this in general. Some packages might assume that the main document text isn't at different scoping levels (e.g., with home-grown counters, or document-spanning variables).