# Roman numeral page numbering

Tags: page-numbering, roman-numerals

I am writing a thesis that contains an abstract and acknowledgements page, but need to number the page numbers using Roman numerals. How would I do this? I don't want to include the title page but would like to start the abstract with roman numeral ii.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! What document class (e.g. `report`) do you use?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/741/roman-numeral-numbering-for-introductions help?

Comment: Mico's answer is closest to your question in the title. - - Not the accepted answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir), you can use any page contents with an `empty` pagestyle for your unnumbered title page, and then use the `\frontmatter` command to set lowercase Roman numerals as the default page numbers.

In my university's case, since I'm using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and other packages, I've found it's best to let the unnumbered first page be numbered with alph format, the rest of the front matter pages use Roman numbering, and the main matter pages use Arabic numbering. This avoids the dreaded "pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored" messages.

Our unnumbered first page includes:

```
\pagenumbering{alph}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

and `\frontmatter` at the end of the page.

In the main thesis file, we put `\mainmatter` right before we include the chapter files. Details as of 2011/08/15 at [this site](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/ttuthesis/browser/trunk?rev=65) (particularly ttuthesis.sty and thesis-manual.tex -- thesis.tex will be updated later).

---

In response to comments, here's a simple example similar to what I use normally. Since I try to isolate my users from the guts of the style file, I separate out the page layout (my problem, and the graduate school's) with the page contents (their problem).

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\title{My Thesis Title}
\author{Me, The Author}

% Define the (unnumbered) title page layout here
\newcommand{\mytitlepage}{
\pagenumbering{alph}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\beforepartskip
\begin{center}
\thetitle

\theauthor
\end{center}
\afterpartskip
\newpage
}

% Define the abstract page layout (numbered ii) here
\newcommand{\abstractpage}{
\frontmatter
\setcounter{page}{2}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}
Abstract: \thetitle
\end{center}

\theabstract
\newpage
}

% Define the abstract page contents here
\newcommand{\theabstract}{
Abstract content goes here.
}

\begin{document}
\mytitlepage
\abstractpage
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
This is chapter 1.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am actually a newbie to tex. My document is a memoir. I don't know where to put these commands. Do I put it on the actual abstract and acknowledgements page? or place the commands between the "packages!}}}" commands?

Comment: Updated my answer with a short example.

Comment: @Mike: Just out of curiosity: are both `\thispagestyle` and `\pagestyle` necessary?

Comment: I could have sworn there times I've experienced `\pagestyle` only affecting following pages (and not the current page), but I may have been misusing it, or getting hit with an unrelated bug elsewhere. This particular code is trimmed down from my regular thesis style, and I didn't put too much effort into minimizing it.

Since this does work with just `\pagestyle`, I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 25):

At the appropriate location (on the page for which you want to change the numbering format), you could redefine the numbering of the counter `page` to roman by using

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}% Roman numerals for page counter
```

By "at the appropriate location" is meant that you can temporarily switch to one numeration style/format, and then switch back at another location by means of

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}% Arabic numerals for page counter
```

Also, if you want the counter `page` to start with something different, try

```
\setcounter{page}{2}% Start page number with 2
```

For more details on counter formatting in LaTeX, see the [Help page on LaTeX Counters](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-3.html) page.

Comment: Changing the \thepage command might confuse some things, therefore \pagenumbering{roman} and \pagenumbering{arabic} (and maybe \setcounter{page}{2}, if still necessary) are safer to use.

Answer (score 17):

I suggest you use the following commands.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
[preamble stuff]
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} %
[titlepage stuff]
\thispagestyle{empty} % don't show (roman) page number on titlepage
\clearpage 
[more frontmatter pages, e.g., dedication, table of contents, etc]

\clearpage %% start of mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic} % restart page numbers at one, now in arabic style
[rest of document]

\end{document}
```