# Continuing Page Numbering (Roman to Arabic)

Tags: page-numbering

I'm here with weird stuff again.

**How can i continue numbering while changing numbering style to Arabic from Roman?** For example let's assume I have total of 7 pages and I want to number the first 3 of them as : i,ii,iii; then I change back to Arabic again and continue counting as 4,5,6,7.

Comment: If you are using the `book` class then you can use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` to delimit the corresponding parts of your documment. The pages after the mainmatter` command will be numbered with arabic numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Roman numeral page numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25789/5764)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After `\begin{document}` (or in the document preamble), issue

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}% Roman page numbers
```

On the page where you want it to change to Arabic numbering, use

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}% Arabic page numbers
```

The above just modifies the page number/counter printing mechanism. In contrast, using `\pagenumbering{arabic}` will change the numbering to Arabic but also resets the page counter.