# Preserve page numbering in fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm using the `fancyhdr` package to include a header on each page. In order to surpress the section title also being cited in the header of each page, I'm using the command `\fancyhf{}`, however this also erases all page numbers after the first page. Does anybody know how to get them back in?

See code below

```
\documentclass[10pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=1.250in]{geometry}
\singlespacing
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\textcolor{gray}{Mock Draft}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\begin{document}
xxxxx
\clearpage
xxxx
\clearpage
xxxx
\end{document}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You can just put `\thepage` into the appropriate header/footer part (`\rhead`, `\cfoot` ... etc.)

Comment: With your setting the page number *doesn't* appear in the first page. Perhaps you have a `\maketitle` command in your real document.

Comment: @egreg if you comment out `\fancyhf{}` the first page _has_ the page number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with the help of the `afterpage` package.

Before the page where you want the page number begins, put:

```
\afterpage{\cfoot{\thepage}}
```

So, your MWE can be rewritten as:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=1.250in]{geometry}
\singlespacing
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\textcolor{gray}{Mock Draft}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\begin{document}
xxxxx
\afterpage{\cfoot{\thepage}}
\clearpage
xxxx
\clearpage
xxxx
\end{document}
```

Note that I deleted `letter` from the options of the `article` class. The default is already the letter paper and anyway the right option is `letterpaper`.

Answer (score 7):

Using `\fancyhf{}` clears the header and footer of anything. However, if you wish to insert the page number, just add `\thepage` to the appropriate location. If you wish to do this conditionally, that is also possible through something like

```
\fancyhead[L]{\ifnum\value{page}<2\relax\else\thepage\fi}
```

which will place `\thepage` int the `[L]`eft header if its value is at least 2.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need of special settings, assuming you don't want the header in the first page; just define the center footer (or any other field you like) to contain the page number.

```
\documentclass[10pt, letter]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.250in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\textcolor{gray}{Mock Draft}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain} % not needed if a \maketitle command is issued

xxxxx
\clearpage

xxxx
\clearpage

xxxx

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP **do** wants the header in the first page, but doesn't want the page number there.

Comment: @karlkoeller I'm reading the question differently.

Answer (score 0):

After `\begin{document}` (or in the document preamble), issue

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}% Roman page numbers
```

On the page where you want it to change to Arabic numbering, use

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}% Arabic page numbers
```

The above just modifies the page number/counter printing mechanism. In contrast, using `\pagenumbering{arabic}` will change the numbering to Arabic but also resets the page counter.

This text is copied from: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56133/110064 ([Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner))