# How to switch page numbering from roman numerals to arabic numerals

Tags: numbering

If a document does not have chapters but only sections, how does one set up "Introduction" with roman numerals and the body text with arabic numerals?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a few more details. E.g., will "Introduction" be a numbered or an unnumbered section header? And, will there be a page break after the "Introduction" section? Finally, which document class are you using?

Comment: The typical approach would be to issue `\pagenumbering{roman}` followed by `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. `\pagenumbering` resets the page number as well. If you want the numbers to be continues, see [Continuing page numbering (roman to arabic)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56131/5764).

Comment: Don't forget the `\cleardoublepage` in front of the `\pagenumbering{<scheme>}` command. It is important.

Comment: @Johannes_B: is this question about page numbering at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think so. I think it could might as wel be: How can i have `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` with an article class.

Comment: Of course, the question could be much more clear about that, Mico already asked for more information.

Comment: @Johannes_B: It could be about using roman numbers for section numbers as well ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer There is no use in guessing, we will need more information from the original poster.