# Manually setting the page number of specific pages to an arabic letter

Tags: page-numbering

For some pages in a `book` document, I need to manually set the page number to an arabic alphabet character.

For example,
The first page of my document should have `آ` as its page number, and second page should be `ب` and third page should be `ج`.

I don't need the page numbers to be automatically set as the pages with this format are 5 or 6 at most. So manually setting them would work but I can't find any command which allows me to set alphabet characters for a specific page.

Please note that, I don't want to set the page numbers to arabic numbers as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56131/continuing-page-numbering-roman-to-arabic) with this command : `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}`. I need to set the page number to an arabic alphabet character such as `آ`  or `د`.

## What I've Tried:

- `\renewcommand\thepage{آ}` : I've tried doing this before every page that I want to manually set but as soon as I do another `\renewcommand\thepage{ب}`  for the next page, then the first page number is overwritten to `ب`.
- `\setcounter{page}{آ}`: this obviously won't work as it excepts a number and not an alphabet character.

So, is there a way to manually set the page number of specific pages to arabic alphabet characters?

Comment: Take a look to the link above (I think it answers your question. Is it?)

Comment: @koleygr, this is different as it need to set the page number to an arabic alphabet character and not a number.

Comment: Ok.. Sorry thought it was a number... And I supposed to know what arabic numbers are ...

Comment: Before the new `\renewcommand\thepage` use `\clearpage`.

Comment: @Skillmon, that worked perfectly. Please provide an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I would suggest `\let\oldpage\thepage` then `\xdef\thepage{whatever}` and on next page `\let\thepage\theoldpage` and `\stepcounter{page}{-1}` if needed

Comment: Oh, and [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example defines `\arabicalph` as number formatting command like `\arabic` or `\alph` (see `latex.ltx`). Then, the numbering style can be easily switched by `\pagenumbering{arabicalph}`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@arabicalph}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
  \or
    آ%
  \or
    ب%
  \or
    ج%
  % ...
  \else
    \@ctrerr
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\arabicalph}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@arabicalph\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabicalph}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing! This answer also works great in a case when `Table of Contents` could have multiple pages and you want the page number to go to the next letter in the alphabet on each page.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `\clearpage` before the next page begins.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{Z}
\blindtext
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{Y}
\blindtext
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although this solution worked perfectly and I didn't ask for anything more in the question, I went with @Heiko's solution as it solved the case when `Table of Contents` could have multiple pages and you want the page number to go to the next letter in the alphabet on each page.

Comment: @Sobhan don't worry, I prefer his solution, too.