# How to have roman pagenumbering, then arabic pagenumbering, without resetting the page number?

Tags: lyx, page-numbering, thesis, page

First two pages need not have page numbers. So I added **\thispagestyle{empty}** and it worked.

Third page needs to have iii, not i, as the page number. I tried **\pagenumbering{roman}**, but it gives i, instead of iii.

Another stackexchange post ([How to have roman numerals at the beginning of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/741/how-to-have-roman-numerals-at-the-beginning-of-the-document)) is for those who want to reset the page number. But I shouldn't reset. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

(The title and body of the posting are about two different things. I've chosen to answer the question raised by the body of the posting.)

You need to place `\pagenumbering{roman}` immediately after `\begin{document}`. E.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\thispagestyle{empty} % don't show page number (i)
\lipsum[1]            % stuff on page `i' / 
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty} % don't show page number (ii) 
\lipsum[2]            % stuff on page `ii' 
\clearpage            

\lipsum[3]            % stuff on page `iii' // page number IS shown
\clearpage

bla bla bla           % rest of document

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but somehow it seems the 3rd page pagenumber still is i, not iii. I thought your solution was perfect but when I implemented it, it doesn't work on my document...

Comment: Oh I found out that this works if 3rd page contains normal texts as in your example, but it doesn't work (page numbering on 3rd page becomes i, not iii) if "\tableofcontents{}" is included in 3rd page.

Comment: @user42459 - Sorry, but the behavior you describe in the second comment does *not* occur if the `article` document class is employed. (You may verify this by, e.g., replacing `\lipsum[3]` with `\tableofcontents` and `bla bla bla` with `\pagenumbering{arabic} \section{Introduction}`, followed by two [2] LaTeX runs.) Which document class do you employ? Do you maybe load any special packages that affect the page numbering algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want a book,  were as usual, the main matter pages have arabic numbers  while front pages have roman numbers, except the page title, that obviously do not need any numeration.

If this is true, well... then just make a book with the `scrbook` class, add a front matter with a tittle, and finally a main matter with chapters o whatever, but without messing with page counters:

```
\documentclass[article]{scrbook}% or \documentclass{book} 
% \usepackage{clrdblpg} % for book only 
\title{foo}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle       % Title page (i) and blank page (ii)
\tableofcontents % page iii and blank page (iv)
\mainmatter
\chapter{bar} % page 1 and blank page (2)
\chapter{baz} % page 3
\end{document}
```

With the standard `book` class the blank pages have the same numeration, but numbers are not suppressed in blank pages. Using `\usepackage{clrdblpg}` the result will  be the same at this respect.

Comment: It's actually an article. Mico suggested some solution. His solution works on the sample he provided. But it somehow doesn't work on my document. My document's 3rd page is just a table of contents "\tableofcontents{}". If I remove "\tableofcontents{}" and fill in some texts, then it works. It's really strange

Comment: The `scrbook` have an article mode (I edited the answer to show it) where the chapters look like sections, so it is easy to adapt this class to make an article and,  at the same time, front pages with Roman numerals.